# Ajax status code 0 on page reload

Tags: jquery, ajax, response, http-status-codes, pageload

I have an application, which retrieves some page data via $.ajax call on **page load** (no other bindings, like 'click' etc.). In a scenario, when user reloads page (or navigates to another page) before the response arrives, the application returns an error (error event [ajaxError()](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxError/) is triggered) with status code 0.

When I was doing my homework and read around SO (and lots of other places) I came across the posts where people simply ignored errors of this kind by doing the following:

```
$(document).ajaxError(function(e, jqxhr, settings, exception) {  
  if (jqxhr.readyState == 0 || jqxhr.status == 0) {  
    return; //Skip this error  
  }  
});
```

Is it safe to presume that only this kind of errors will be ignored? Can any negative scenarios appear that would need 'special attention'?

ALSO:

I've found some replies to similar issues stating that putting 'return false;' or 'preventDefault' solved their issue. But in my case everything is happening on page load, so I can't 'hook' on any of mentioned events... Or can I?

**EDIT:** The additional question here is: is there any other way of handling these situations (ajax request being interrupted by page reload)? The thing is that I have error reporting bound on the general ajaxError event and I'd like to filter out messages like this (or maybe even prevent them from happening in the first place)?

Comment: Where have you seen this? "0" isn't even a valid status code.

Comment: Status code 0 means that jqxhr object isn't initialized. I can see this code if I put _console.log(jqxhr.status);_  in _.ajaxError_ event (as described above) and reload page multiple times (to interrupt the request before response).

Answer (score 1):

This will ignore all errores returned from ajax calls.  It's sort-of-safe: users will never notice that the error ocurred.  Hard to say outside any concrete example, but your application will probably break when it does an AJAX call that fails, unless each handler handles the error accordinly.

Comment: The only question which pops up is: are there any other possible errors that can match mentioned condition (status code = 0, ready state = 0)? That's what I mean by asking 'Is this method safe?'. I wouldn't want to filter out any other scenarios except this one...

Comment: I really want to know how to do this too!

Answer (score 1):

In response to your question "is it safe", my answer is, yes it is safe.  I have been using it since past couple of months and it works great for me.

However, below api documentation shades more information on error object.  I haven't moved to jQuery 1.9* yet, but it's still good.

For more information:
http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/#jqXHR